# Combine match and lookup in MongoDB aggregate with a boolean OR

Tags: mongodb

I want to accomplish the following SQL like operation in MongoDB

```
SELECT contentItem._id, contentitem.text
FROM contentItems
WHERE contentItem.metadata.color = 'yellow'
UNION
SELECT contentItem._id, contentitem.text
FROM contentItems
WHERE contentItems.contentSets IN (
    SELECT contentSet._id FROM contentSets WHERE contentSet.metadata.color= 'yellow'
)
```

this can also be done like this

```
SELECT contentItem._id, contentitem.text
FROM contentItems
WHERE (
    contentItem.metadata.color = 'yellow'
) OR contentItems.contentSets IN (
    SELECT contentSet._id FROM contentSets WHERE contentSet.metadata.color = 'yellow'
)
```

I can do both halves of this

```
db.getCollection('contentItems').aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'metadata.color': { '$eq': 'yellow' }
        }
    }
])
```

and

```
db.getCollection('contentItems').aggregate([
    {'$unwind': '$contentSets'},
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'contentSets',
            'localField': 'contentSets',
            'foreignField': '_id',
            'as': 'matchedContentSets'
        }
    },
    {
        '$match': {
            'matchedContentSets.metadata.color': { '$eq': 'yellow' }
        }
    }
])
```

but I don't know how to get a UNION of this data.

Comment: Could you paste sampe docs and expected output ?

Comment: And sample output as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out out use an `$or` operator in the match

```
db.getCollection('contentItems').aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'contentSets',
            'localField': 'contentSets',
            'foreignField': '_id',
            'as': 'matchedContentSets'
        }
    },
    {
        '$match': {
            '$or': [
                { 'metadata.color': { '$eq': 'yellow' } },
                { 'matchedContentSets.metadata.color': { '$eq': 'yellow' } },
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'matchedContentSets': 0
        }
    }
])
```